# Printer function in PHP cannot print Chinese character (UTF-8)

Tags: php, printing, utf-8

I use printer function to print out some data in a text file (.txt) that contains Chinese and English word. Both of them can display correctly in the webpage. When printing, the English word looks well but the Chinese word doesn't show the correct output. Any suggestion to overcome this? below is my coding. Please help me.

```
<?php
$print = file_get_contents("print.txt");
$printer = "XP-80"; //printer name
echo $print;
if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
{  
   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
   printer_write($ph, $print); 
   printer_close($ph); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your printer supports Chinese characters in UTF-8? Just because your text displays on screen, it doesn't mean that it will necessarily appear correctly elsewhere.

Comment: ya. The printer can support Chinese characters.
If i use window.print , the Chinese char will be fine but if i use Printer function in PHP , its does not work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I can think of that might be the cause of the issue:

- The font you've selected is not UTF-8 compatible.
- There's also a note on the [manual page](http://no.php.net/printer_set_option) for `printer_set_option()` about a bug. It's from 2009, so not sure if it's still valid.

*Edit after you comment:*

Try this example from [reference manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-select-font.php)

```
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 148, 76, PRINTER_FW_MEDIUM, false, false, false, -50);
printer_select_font($ph, $font);
```

Comment: which is the column should I put in utf8 ?

Comment: The properties of this function is `printer_create_font ( string $face , int $height , int $width , int $font_weight , bool $italic , bool $underline , bool $strikeout , int $orientation )` as described at reference manual. You can try to change the font at `$face` property to find a UTF-8 compatible font.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve this problem:

```
$textprinting = "your text";
utf8_decode($textprinting);
```